# Git GUI error when fetching (error 503) a branch from GitLab repository

Tags: git, gitlab, branching-and-merging, git-fetch

Edit:  Splitting the question into 2:  1) 503 error, 2) how to get a file from one repo into another.  This question focuses on the 503 error:

I'm new to git GUI. I'm trying to to get a file that is in my master branch onto my `development` branch.

I found somewhere on stackoverflow that I need to fetch All, then do a merge with my local `development` branch (checked out previously). However, when I try to do the fetch, I get the following error:

```
Fetching development
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/<myrepo address>/vivado-user-ip/-/branches/': The requested URL returned error: 503
error: Could not fetch development
```

If I fetch the `master`, by itself (fetch from `origin`), there is no issue. When I fetch from `development` or fetch all, I get the error.

What does error 503 refer to? In my case, it does not appear to be the `http.proxy` environment variable issue - I already checked that.
Edit:  in response to @Daemon Painter, I'm adding a link to various post discussing the [environment variable a cause for the fetch error](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/503-error-when-fetching/551)

Comment: May I suggest you open a new question for the second part? It doesn't seem to be related to the solution of error 503.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066100/git-pull-error-the-requested-url-returned-error-503-while-accessing) is related, but not applicable (?) and [this](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/503-error-when-fetching/551/6), I assume, is the proxy variable issue - you'd get a +1 for [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64506309/edit) that into your question. So if it is not the [proxy issue on GitLab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29476327/gitlab-the-requested-url-returned-error-503), did you check if your server is up and running?

Comment: Thank you. I can, but in my case the second is the main question, as stated in the 2nd sentence in the post.  The error occurs as I"m trying to do that, and understanding the error is only relevant so I can achieve the goal of copying a file from the master branch into the existing development branch.   As you can see, I am a nube using git, git gui --so I can be obfuscating the issue.  If you still think it is better to split them into the error, and then the moving a file from one repo to another, I will do that.

Comment: yes, you are obfuscating the issue. 503 is a network issue: the remote server is not resopnding. Did you check that "https://gitlab.com/<myrepo address>/vivado-user-ip/-/branches/" can be reached?

Comment: yes....it is not a network issue.  and I will split the question.  thank you.